# Not getting the exact data at server sent from client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, struct, client-server

I am writing a client / server system in which the client sends a record from client to server.  I am trying to represent the data as a `struct`, but I do not successfully `recv()` the `struct` at the server end.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 

#pragma pack(1)
struct emp
{
    int id;
    char *name;
} emp1, emp3;
#pragma pack(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    char recvBuff[1024];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    memset(recvBuff, '0', sizeof(recvBuff));
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 
    serv_addr.sin_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.105");

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 

    emp1 = (struct emp *) malloc(sizeof(struct emp));
    emp1.name = (char *) malloc((size)*(sizeof(char)));
    printf("Enter name of employee : ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", emp1.name);
    printf("Enter emp id : ");
    scanf(" %d", &emp1.id);
    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(regn));
    memcpy(data, &regn, sizeof(regn));
    sendto(sockfd, data, sizeof(emp1), 0, (SOCKADDR *) &serv_addr,
            sizeof(serv_addr));

    close(sockfd);
}
```

and my server is like this

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>

struct emp
{
    int id;
    char *name;
} emp1, emp3; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    char recvBuf[1025];

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    listen(listenfd, 10); 
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 

    if(recvfrom(sd, recvBuf, recvBufSize, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &len) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error receiving message from client\n");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Message received:%s\n", recvBuf);
       printf("Size :%d\n", strlen(recvBuf));
       memcpy(&emp1, recvBuf, sizeof(emp));
       printf("name:%s\n", emp1.name );
       printf("is:%d\n", emp1.id);
    }
```

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends. and `sizeof char` will never be other than `1` - this is defined by the standard.

Comment: You are 100% sure server and client use the same struct layout end endianess? It is generally a bad idea to send binary images of structured data between different systems. Use proper serialisation of the fields instead.

Comment: @olaf what should i do then? i want to send a record from client to server

Comment: Please read comments completely! I presume you are able to use a search engine of your choice.

Comment: Server: what is 'sd' in  'if(recvfrom(sd, recvBuf, recvBufSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &len) < 0)'?  The client<> server socket, as returned by accept(), is 'connfd'.  Even if you did receive anything, you are assuming a  null-terminated string in  'recvBuf' - something that is certainly not guaranteed.  You MUST correctly handle the result returned by recv(), or recvfrom(), when dealing with SOCK_STREAM's.  You should understand what strlen() and printf("%s..") do.

Comment: Essentially, 99.9% of all network code that is posted on SO with strlen() in it is borken.

Comment: 'memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); - where is 'sendbuf' declared?

Comment: I cannot understand why the server did not just fall over immediate with a huge pile of faults, eg. 'socket operation on non-socket', or, for that matter, how it compiled at all.

Comment: Hmm.. I know this may sound like a strange question but.... is this code real?

Comment: @MartinJames actually what i need to do is send a record from client to server.If you think to send a record we dont need structure please tell me otherwise how can be done

Comment: "memset(sendBuff, **'0'**, ..." - Really?

Comment: @Olaf ^^^^  lol, neven even noticed that:)

Comment: "accept(listenfd, ** (struct sockaddr*)** NULL" ? (hmm. bold does not work) I'd say this code is broken by design. No offense, but please read the basics (again)

Comment: @Olaf lol, ^^^ markdown fail.  Still, I'm sure that you're right in that the server code cannot run correctly, even if it compiles, which it does not:(

Comment: I voted to reopen this question. The problem is pretty clear, he is sending a pointer instead of the full name. There is even a perfectly good answer to that question. If there is a reason to close this question, you might as well close all questions for the same reasons.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck no, there is more than one problem.  The fact that the server will not compile is one of them.  If it will not compile, it cannot be run.  If the server cannot run, the client cannot connect.  If the client cannot connect, it cannot send the bad pointer, (yes - a big problem, but not the biggest:).

Answer (score 1):

you are sending a struct which contains an integer and a char **pointer**. This pointer points to a completly random location, on the receiving system.
You have to send the content `name` points to.

You could send every member of the struct on its own. For members with variable length, you have to send the size first and allocate it on the receiving end.

As stated by John Bollinger: One of your structs is packed, the other not. this may cause additional problems with layout and size of the struct and is probably unnecessary .

Comment: Additionally, one source uses `#pragma pack` and the other does not.  That may cause the two programs to have different ideas about the layout and even the size of the structure.  There is no particular reason to pack the structure; that would be better dropped.

Comment: @robin.koch what needs to be done

Comment: @user3145350: see my edit.

Comment: Don't worry about what the client sends too much - the server is not gonna receive anything anyway:(

Comment: now that you say it... maybe not the actual code, or too less information on the actual problems/errors.

Comment: @robin.koch  actually what i need to do is send a record from client to server.If you think to send a record we dont need structure please tell me otherwise how can be done

Comment: You need serialisation. This is the process where for instance the name, first the length is written, and then the individual charackters, at the receiving side you do the opposite, you receive the length first and allocate enough charakters for the actual name charakters, or you use a struct that does not contain any pointers at all but a fixed size name.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck can you give me the pseudo code for structure that doesnot contain pointers

Comment: @PhilipStuyck actually i have made the code its running where can i share with you, either u send me a test mail on gunjanmehta08@gmail.com. or tell how to share

Comment: @PhilipStuyck its running but i need to ask few things

Comment: I am going on a well earned vacation tomorrow. I don't have access to my mails for 8 days.

Answer (score 0):

Added this answer to answer to specific questions of the OP (it may seem a bit off track of the original question).

An example of simple streaming. It is simple because in a real streaming scenario you need object id's to be able to instantiate and load the real classes. But if you know already what class you are sending or receiving, their is no need for this complexity. If you are sending multiple instances of classes then you need a more complex streaming mechanism. As microsoft did for instance in MFC, Borland in OWL, .NET also has mechanisms in place, ...

```
namespace OMCIPoco{

typedef std::vector<unsigned char> ucharvector;

SystemData::stream& operator <<(SystemData::stream& stream,const ucharvector& data);
SystemData::stream& operator >>(SystemData::stream& stream,ucharvector& data);

}
```

The cpp file :

```
SystemData::stream& operator <<(SystemData::stream& stream,const ucharvector& data)
{
    stream << (unsigned long)data.size();
    for (ucharvector::const_iterator it=data.begin();it<data.end();++it)
        stream << *it;
    return stream;
}
SystemData::stream& operator >>(SystemData::stream& stream,ucharvector& data)
{
    unsigned long count;
    stream >> count;
    data.reserve(count);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<count;++i){
        unsigned char c;
        stream >> c;
        data.push_back(c);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Notice how the << and >> are in balance.
The stream is an interface that makes abstraction of the medium you are streaming to, it can be memory or disk or a networkstream. I can solve little endian problems using the streaming concept here as well, because the stream knows how to (de)serialise shorts, longs, ..., and it knows howto buffer as well.

You can use a flat structure as well avoiding the above complexity completely

```
class data{
public:
   char name[20];
};
```

now using sizeof(data) will be correct because you will send the entire data struct. I used class here but struct works just the same way. The downside is that if the name contains only 10 charakters you will still send 20.